# spark error - getting installation eror

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

After installing Spark and running

```
C:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
```

I am getting following error - any advice?

```
C:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-08-05 01:29:36 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have the right java or scala version.

Please note that Spark 2.3.1 runs on

```
Java 8+, 
Python 2.7+/3.4+ and
R 3.1+.
```

For the Scala API, Spark 2.3.1 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

Please check the below 2 things-
1. Check the java version installed on your machine where you are submitting your spark application

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

2. check the scala version

   `scala -version`

Comment: Thanks; yes - reinstalled Java/jdf 8 - working fine now.